# Django - Query set is not displaying the result from db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, python-requests

I have values stored in the db but it is not displaying the query set

[image: View.py]

Models.py

[image: Models.py]

empty query set-------
[28/Mar/2020 16:31:25] "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 34

Comment: Please use ` symbols to represent your code.

Comment: Please post your code in code snippets so that we can copy and run your code to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
p = Product objects.all()
context = {'p': p}
```

In template:

```
{% for product in p %}
{{ product.name }}
{{ product.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know what you got.

Comment: @Gowtham...im glad I could help. You can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The objects have to be created using Django's QuerySet API, you can't use data that's already present in the Database.

Run the command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Now import your Product model just as you did in the views.py and test by adding an item:

```
from products.models import Product
p = Product(name='test', price=25.5, stock=1, image_url='/abc')
p.save()
```

Run your code again, you can see the object is in your database now.

For more information check the [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)